# Couldn't understand main drawback of Decorator Pattern

Tags: design-patterns, decorator

I am learning `Decorator Pattern`. It is very powerful pattern, and quite useful. The objective of the pattern is simple, adding(extending) behaviour to objects at runtime without recompiling source code by composition and delegation, hence provides an alternative to subclassing for extending behaviour. However, I read one of the main drawbacks of this pattern and could not quite understand it. Here is the statement:

> "People sometimes take a piece of client code that **relies on
>   specific types and introduce decorators** without thinking through
>   everything. Now, one great thing about me is that you can usually
>   insert decorators transparently and the client never has to know it's
>   dealing with a decorator. But like I said, some code is **dependent on
>   specific types** and when you start introducing decorators, boom! Bad
>   things happen."

Taken from "Head first design patterns"

What does the author mean by "relying on specific types". If possible, please with real world and simple examples

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sometimes you have code that does type checks like in java

```
a instanceof B
```

or even

```
a.getClass == B.class
```

This kind of check breaks

If a is no longer a B but a decorator D wrapped around an A

To give a specific example:

```
I b = new B; // I is an interface implemented by B
b = D(b); // the decorator D implements I as well
doSomething(b);
```

with doSomething defined as follows:

```
doSomething(I i){
    if i instanceof B
        doThis();
    else
        doThat();
}
```

By introducing the decorator D the behavior changed from `doThis()` to `doThat()`

A real world example where this happens a lot is with Hibernate. It generates under certain circumstances proxies around entities which provide additional Hibernate specific behavior. If the code using those entities does checks as the one described above, it will break depending on how the entities where created. Actually the instance of might work, but the getClass() variant will definitely fail.

Comment: Thank you, now I surely understand the drawback of the pattern :)

Comment: And one more question based on your answer, What should I do if I face the situation you mentioned above, what is the workaround?

Comment: Don't use checks like the ones described, and double check if such checks are present when you consider introducing a Delegate

Comment: @Jens Schauder - I want to say again, despite my post, excellent answer!  demonstrative, to the point and clearly laid out :)

Answer (score 1):

Taking nothing away from the excellent answer provided by Jens; it perfectly represents the view of the author and many other programmers.

This viewpoint, however, is outdated and pedagogical.

First, the example used by Jens is often cited, but it is not the acceptably correct construction of a decorator. Some correct constructions of decorator or wrapper would be as follows:

**using compositional inheritance:**

a instance of B

*Composed this way any comparison of D to a remains functional*

Decorator D extends B and implements Interface C (new functionality)

*a can be assigned as a D and this remains remains functional*

**using interface encapsulation:**

interface C has a Decorator D (new functionality) whose Method(s) M wrap D

A extends B and Implements C

*A is also an instance of B and remains functional*

**using inversion of control**

*This is similar, but a little less obvious it helps if you're familiar with IoC*

A extends B and can be constructed or injected with a D whose functionality is wrapped by Methods M.

a instance of A is dynamically bound to instances requiring B

*this binding is functional for all cases of B*

d instance of D is injected at runtime where it's functionality is needed for A

For the most part flaws in decorator implementations are the fault of bad design or implementation. Further decorators are used all the time for high availability applications.

Real World examples, Every GUI, WYSWIG Editor, Web Browser, and IDE you're likely to use, as well as every Programming Language Interpreter, Game Engine, Photo Editor, mobile or web app, oh and CSS and SVG Renders, and in fact almost any modern render pipeline is a special case of a decorator pattern. So I guess I'm saying, respect the decorator.